# Combine SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine two very similar SQL queries with separate date ranges to produce a single output table. (to compare results from this week with the corresponding week last year.)

I've had a bit of a trawl of SO and found some similar questions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557722/how-can-i-combine-sql-queries-with-different-expressions)) but still haven't managed to get this working:

The two queries are:

```
SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT([arrpoint]) AS NumberOfTimesTW
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
    AND [booked] >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
ORDER BY NumberOfTimesTW DESC
```

and:

```
SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT([arrpoint]) AS NumberOfTimesTW
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
    AND [booked] >= DateAdd(wk,-52,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
    AND [booked] <= DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
ORDER BY NumberOfTimesTW DESC
```

These ouput:

```
arrpoint | NumberOfTimesTW
  abc    |        3
  def    |        2
```

and:

```
arrpoint | NumberOfTimesTWLY
  ghi    |        5
  klm    |        4
  abc    |        1
```

What I'm hoping to get is something like:

```
arrpoint | NumberOfTimesTW | NumberOfTimesTWLY
  abc    |       3         |          1
  def    |       2         |
  ghi    |                 |          5
  klm    |                 |          4
```

Not knowing much about SQL I'd originally thought I'd be able to achieve this just by sticking `UNION` between the two queries but no luck.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Case` inside your aggregation to simplify the query

```
SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT( case when [booked] >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
        THEN [arrpoint]
        END) AS NumberOfTimesTW
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN ([booked] >= DateAdd(wk,-52,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
    AND [booked] <= DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)))
        THEN [arrpoint]
        END) AS NumberOfTimesTWLY
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
AND (
    [booked] >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    OR(
            [booked] >= DateAdd(wk, - 52, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
            AND [booked] <= DateAdd(wk, - 51, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
            )
        )
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
ORDER BY NumberOfTimesTW DESC
```

Comment: This is the approach I would use, but it would probably be wise to filter the rows in the where clause, there seems little point in scanning rows that won't be counted by either `COUNT` column

Comment: @GarethD  I missed that. Updated the code now. Thanks.

Comment: This worked an absolute treat. Thank you very muchly. =)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use full join ( assuming you want all values from both tables) on the second query

```
select  a.[arrpoint], NumberOfTimesTW, NumberOfTimesTW1 
from
(
(SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT([arrpoint]) AS NumberOfTimesTW
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
    AND [booked] >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
ORDER BY NumberOfTimesTW DESC) as a 
full join
(SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT([arrpoint]) AS NumberOfTimesTW1
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
    AND [booked] >= DateAdd(wk,-52,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
    AND [booked] <= DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
ORDER BY NumberOfTimesTW DESC) as b)
on a.[arrpoint] =b.[arrpoint]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with a as (
SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT([arrpoint]) AS NumberOfTimesTW
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
    AND [booked] >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
)
,b as (
SELECT
    [arrpoint]  
    ,COUNT([arrpoint]) AS NumberOfTimesTW
FROM  [groups] tb1
    INNER JOIN [fileinfo] tb2 ON tb1.op_name = tb2.[operator]
    INNER JOIN [costs] tb4 ON tb2.[fileno] = tb4.[fileno]
WHERE 
    [bedbank] = 1 
    AND [booked] >= DateAdd(wk,-52,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
    AND [booked] <= DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
GROUP BY [ arrpoint] HAVING (COUNT([arrpoint])>1)
)
select 
  [arrpoint]
  ,a.NumberOfTimesTW
  ,b.NumberOfTimesTW as NumberOfTimesTWLY
from a
full join b
  on a.[arrpoint] = b.[arrpoint]
```

Comment: This answer is correct (apart from the fact that you can't use `ORDER BY` in derived tables), but I don't see how anyone can find it useful. There is no explanation as to what you have done at all, code only answers are very rarely good answers.

Comment: I agree with the order by, I didn't even see it as it was a copy from his code. I always give explanations where there is the need for one. Now, to give explanations for a full join .. well .. I do not think there is a need for that. But haters gonna hate :)

Comment: As you have said, it is a fairly simple answer, so you don't have to give an essay, but just a short explanation makes the answer much more digestible. Could be as simple as "I have taken each of the two individual queries from the question and placed each inside a [Common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), then finally I have used a [full join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) to combine the two data sets." - The answer is only obvious when you know it!

Comment: I would not say I am a hater, I don't think I have had any previous interaction with you, and less than 10% of my overall votes are down votes. I just think that this site is not just for the benefit of the person answering the question, other people will have a similar issue and end up here, and unless they have the same database this answer is useless, whereas if you discuss the basics of what you have done the next person can apply the same principles to their problem. The issue of code only answers has been [discussed on Meta extensively](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274)